# Chrome App - Pinned in Manifest

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension, manifest, pinned-site

I'm putting together a hosted Chrome app. Is it possible to specify the app as "pinned" in the manifest, so that when the user opens it, it is automatically opened as a pinned tab?

I saw [this](http://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/tabs.html) but I'm not sure if it would work with hosted apps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

The docs link you gave is for only extensions. There is no option to make pinned the hosted app's tab in [manifest.json for apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#manifest).